# Blazor MS SQL Server: Login failed for user/ No process at end of pipeline error

Tags: sql-server, iis, blazor

I'm trying to connect my Blazor project to a MS SQL server with IIS, yet I keep getting two errors.

The first error I get when I initially try to connect which is as follows:

> Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
> ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (233): No process is on the other end of the pipe.

The second error I get when I reload the page as is as follows:

> Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'User1'.

From what I've gathered it looks like some sort of permissions problem on the Server but I cant figure out where or what exactly needs to be changed. These are some of the common issues I've tried.

Server Authentication: SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode.

Allow remote connections: true.

User1: Seems to has access/permission to everything.

Also I've check the SQL log and error found there is:

> Login failed for user 'User1'.Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided.[CLIENT: ] Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State:5

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) seems to confirm: State 5 means "User ID is not valid." A couple of possibilities... 1) SQL/Windows logins are configured on a per-instance basis - does the target server host multiple instances and are you connecting to the right one? 2) If you don't specify a Database/Initial Catalog in the connection string the login's "Default Database" settings apply - is the login mapped to a Database User with sufficient access there?

Comment: Blazor server or WASM? Edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: You need to qualify: 1. Is the server remote or local to the IIS server, local/remote to your dev system.  If remote can you access the server from your dev system with Management Studio/Visual Studio/whatever your using to manage the database on the server. 2. Show us your connection string - with false credentials. 3. What framework are you using to access the database - Entity Framework, ?

Comment: 1. The Server is local to the IIS Server, I have other databases set up that are accessed without any issues.

2. Connection String doesn't seem to be the issue as I have another application with the same format that works.-- Data Source=Server; Initial Catalog=Database; User Id=User1;Password=blahblah1; ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite

3. using Dapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable TCP\IP protocol and then test it again.

Steps as next:

1. Turn off your firewall and antivirus software.
2. Enable the TCP\IP protocol both in server and client side and use 1433 port.
3. Restart the SQL Service and try again.

More detail steps: [setting-up-management-studio-for-remote-sql-server](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/setting-up-management-studio-for-remote-sql-server)

More helpful information: [how-to-connect-to-a-remote-sql-server](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-sql-server)